# Center an embedded youtube video in a UIWebview Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, youtube, uiwebview

I have a webveiw with a youtube video i embedded.It work fine and all but the problem is I want it to be entered and be the size of the width of the web view. Right now it is to the left side and not expanded to the other size. The hight is fine but I want the width fixed.

where player is the uiview
Here is what I have so far:

```
    let myVideo = "https://myvideo"

    let myHTML = "<iframe width=\"\(player.frame.size.width)\" height=\"\(player.frame.size.height)\" src=\"\(myVideo)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"


    player.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    player.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: nil)
    player.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


    player.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    player.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(250)
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to use https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper, Its official way to do it. Give it try, you don't need to write html and css yourself.

**Sample Usage**

1) Add pod in your project

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'
```

2) Add `UIView` in xib and change its class to `YTPlayerView`

3) Create IBOutlet for `YTPlayerView`

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;
```

4) In `ViewController.m`

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                              @"playsinline"    : @1,
                              @"showinfo"       : @0,
                              @"rel"            : @0,
                              @"controls"       : @1,
                              @"origin"         : @"https://www.example.com", // this is critical
                              @"modestbranding" : @1
                            };

[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"Youtube Video Id" playerVars:playerVars];
```

For complete documentation please visit.
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: Im giving you the answer because that is what I went with. The others were close but didn't work exactly as I needed it to do. Thank you. You have to do it a bit different with swift than what is posted on the website because they only use objective c there

Comment: Consider using Objective-C in swift.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used in an App to show a YouTube video centered in my UIWebView.

```
let width: CGFloat = player.frame.size.width
let height = ceil((width / 16) * 9) // Assuming that the videos aspect ratio is 16:9

let htmlString = "<div style='text-align: center;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(width)' height='\(height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(youtubeVideoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></div>"
```

Comment: I used this in a Swift application.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `align="middle"` complete code below

```
let myVideo = "https://myvideo"

    let myHTML = "<iframe align=\"middle\" width=\"\(player.frame.size.width)\" height=\"\(player.frame.size.height)\" src=\"\(myVideo)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"


    player.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    player.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: nil)
    player.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


    player.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    player.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(250)
```

Comment: or you can create a outer div with your alignments and add iframe with style 'display:block;'

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"315\"
```